# Complier error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 while trying to open a window with glfw

Tags: c, macos, glfw

I am trying to create a window with GLFW in an openGL project and when I compile the code it gives me this error message:

```
  "_glfwCreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in main-38dd4e.o
  "_glfwInit", referenced from:
      _main in main-38dd4e.o
  "_glfwMakeContextCurrent", referenced from:
      _main in main-38dd4e.o
  "_glfwPollEvents", referenced from:
      _main in main-38dd4e.o
  "_glfwTerminate", referenced from:
      _main in main-38dd4e.o
  "_glfwWindowShouldClose", referenced from:
      _main in main-38dd4e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "glfw-3.3.5.bin.MACOS/include/GLFW/glfw3.h"

int main(){
    GLFWwindow* window;
    glfwInit();
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800,800,"Window",NULL,NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

System setup:

Machine: Macbook pro intel core i5

OS: MacOS Monterey v12.0.1

Comment: How are you compiling the code? It looks like you aren't linking some required glfw libraries.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll have a look